# How to solve problem with OctoPrint webcam rotation

Tags: octoprint

I have a problem with my OctoPrint setup. No matter if I check any of these options, image looks just like attached below - with front side on the left-top instead of bottom-right.

- Flip webcam horizontally
- Flip webcam vertically
- Rotate webcam 90 degrees counter clockwise

I use OctoPi, flashed today, 2023-02-21. Is there something in the advanced options I could use to rotate my webcam image the way I need it to be? Camera is glued to the ceiling of my LackRack, That's why it's upside down. This is the only place that works well with it's focal length that's too long for any other place than a corner farthest away from the center of my printing bed.

[image: Webcam image]
[image: Options image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the workings of OctoPrint, (and I may be totally wrong) but I would imagine that it uses gStreamer to stream the video. Is there a text config file that OctoPrint uses, which contains a gStreamer configuration string? Or maybe the gstreamer string is in the UI (advanced) settings somewhere? If so, then that string could be modified to rotate, or flip, the image. If I have time I will also try to do some research into how OctoPrint manages its stream..

Comment: Additional info that might be useful for us to know: What OS is the Pi running? What Pi is it? Also, are you using a Pi Camera via CSI or a USB webcam? How is it connected, Wi-Fi or Ethernet? Please [edit] your answer and add that info.